# How to use custom placeholders when sharing projects in Figma?

Tags: user-experience, adobe-xd, figma, e-mail, placeholder

So I have designed a website in Figma that I want to share with multiple clients. I want to personalize the content of the project as in the nav-brand or any other content.

For instance, if a customer X is viewing the project then he must see his company name X and if another customer Y is viewing the same project he must see his company name Y in the navbar and so on.

- Is there a way to create multiple instances of this project automatically that I can share?
- Can I add a placeholder in the project file and use a .csv file with personalized content that fills up automatically when sending bulk email?
- If Figma doesn't support placeholders, is there any other software that you can recommend for my use case like Adobe XD?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK no; you can share only the current version of the file and there isn't a way to import CSV data (although [there is a feature request in their forum](https://spectrum.chat/figma/feature-requests/feature-request-using-real-data-in-design~8205378f-ea98-4e8e-9aa2-ae249b82d2ea)).

However you can

- make these customizable elements as [Components](https://help.figma.com/search?collectionId=5ab59c612c7d3a0e9366b236&query=component) and add them to a [Team Library](https://help.figma.com/article/238-shared-resources)
- duplicate your project file for each client
- customize the component in the project file (you can change text, colors, effects) for each client. This way each different design will have its own URL when you share it.

I'm not sure about Adobe XD, you probably would have to [create your own plugin](https://helpx.adobe.com/xd/help/plugins.html) or customize the [Data Populator](https://www.datapopulator.com/)(it is finicky though). On Invision Craft you can also pull real data but at the time of the file creation, not dynamically from the sharing link as far as I understand.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I've only been looking into Figma for the past few days. It would be awesome if they implement this feature. Good for bulk customized marketing.

Comment: If they have an API to create custom components and API to pick these components from team library also another API to duplicate the project file then I might as well automate the same in my application. What do you think?

Comment: @abicrazieeee maybe, from their web API documentation: "The Figma API supports read access and interactions with Figma files. This gives you the ability to view and extract any objects or layers, and their properties, so you can render them as images outside of Figma. You can then present your designs, connect them to other applications, or use them to expand on your vision. Future versions of the API will unlock even greater functionality around Files."
https://www.figma.com/developers

Comment: Interesting!, I'll check it out. Will keep you updated with my developments.